# Hot to prevent Too many query rows: 50001 for a batch method

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, batch, childrecords

I have a batch class which I use to update a field of all historic records of an object. I have a trigger on the same object to update the same field when a record is updated.

The trigger does exactly the same update as the batchclass so I made a (child)method in my batchclass which can be called by the execute method of the batch class and the trigger.

since I need to query some child records I have to do a query in the (child)method since I cannot do this in the start method of the batch class.

When I run my batchclass the trigger also gets triggerd so I get an error:
Too many query rows: 50001.

How do I advoid this? Running the batch class only has no issues.

Batchclass

```
public class UpdateCounterEsOnsp implements
Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {
    public String idClause = Label.UpdateCounterEsOnsp;
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(
            'SELECT ID, AVG_ES_Points__c FROM sport__c ' +  idClause +   ' ORDER BY createddate ASC'
        );
    }
    
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sport__c> scope){
        UpdateCounterEsOnsp.UpdateSport(scope);
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        //
    }
    
    public static void UpdateSport(List<sport__c> scope){
                // process each batch of records
        List<sport__c> spList = new List<sport__c>();  
        for (sport__c sp : [SELECT ID,(SELECT id,status__r.name, My_application__r.AVG_Search__c FROM Steps__r ORDER BY createddate ASC) FROM sport__c WHERE id in :scope]){
                                                                for(Step__c st : sp.Steps__r){
                                                                        
                                                                        if(st.status__r.name.contains('1.0')) sp.AVG_ES_Points__c = 1;
                                                                        if(st.status__r.name.contains('2.0')) sp.AVG_ES_Points__c = 2;
                                                                        if(st.status__r.name.contains('3.0')) sp.AVG_ES_Points__c = 3;    
                                                                }
                                                                spList.add(sp);
                                                            }
        update spList;
    }
}
```

After update trigger

```
..
 UpdateCounterEsOnsp.UpdateSport(newList);   
..
```

The purpose is to have the batch proces update the historic records once and after that the trigger will update with the correct values. The batch proces should be ran occasionally if for some reason in the future the trigger didn't work.

Comment: Just a note, you're retrieving N `Step` records, but you're using only the last one. I.E. A Sport record has 3 steps: 3.0, 2.0 and 1.0. On each iteration you overwrite `sp.AVG_ES_Points__c`, so once the for-loop ends it will be `1` (in this example). Is this the desired behavior?

Comment: @RubenDG Thanks. I will add a order by  created date asc so in my case it always will be the highest value present. Any idea on my original question?

Comment: Is `AVG_ES_Points__c` updated only by the trigger and the batch?

Comment: @RubenDG if you mean the field AVG_ES_Points__c Yes. Or do you mean if the record sport__c  could get updated for other reasons?

Comment: The field, thanks. Since it's an after update trigger that update records of the same object, how do you handle recursion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no reason for a Stateful batch here, so if you didn't hide some code that may require it, I would remove `Database.Stateful`. This way it won't go through serialization/deserialization phase, which will increase the time your batch takes to complete.

```java
for (sport__c sp : [SELECT ID,(SELECT id,status__r.name, My_application__r.AVG_Search__c FROM Steps__r ORDER BY createddate ASC) FROM sport__c WHERE id in :scope]){
    for(Step__c st : sp.Steps__r){
            
            if(st.status__r.name.contains('1.0')) sp.AVG_ES_Points__c = 1;
            if(st.status__r.name.contains('2.0')) sp.AVG_ES_Points__c = 2;
            if(st.status__r.name.contains('3.0')) sp.AVG_ES_Points__c = 3;    
    }
    spList.add(sp);
}
```

The issue here is that you retrieve N *Steps* but you use only one. Adding `ORDER BY` is not enough, you should add `LIMIT 1` too. This will help to keep the transaction within the limits (query rows) and will improve the performance too since it will loop over fewer records. Moreover instead of having three separate if-block, it should be a sequence of if-else.
Finally you should check whether `AVG_ES_Points__c` changed or not, instead of updating every Sport record.
So you can change it to:

```java
for (Sport__c sp : [SELECT Id, (SELECT Status__r.Name FROM Steps__r ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC LIMIT 1) FROM Sport__c WHERE id IN :scope]) {
    Decimal esPoints = sp.AVG_ES_Points__c;
    for(Step__c st : sp.Steps__r){
            if (st.status__r.name.contains('3.0')) {
                esPoints = 3;
            } else if (st.status__r.name.contains('2.0')) {
                esPoints = 2;
            } else if (st.status__r.name.contains('1.0')) {
                esPoints = 1;
            }
    }
    
    // Only if AVG_ES_Points__c changed, the record will be updated
    if (esPoints != sp.AVG_ES_Points__c) {
        spList.add(sp);
    }
}
```

Since the `AVG_ES_Points__c` field is updated only by the batch or the trigger, you could modify the after update trigger in order to skip the records updated by the batch: if `AVG_ES_Points__c` hasn't been changed, the trigger should handle that record, otherwise it means that the batch updated it, so you can skip it.

```java
...
List<Sport__c> scope = new List<Sport__c>();
for (Sport__c sport : newList) {
    if (sport.AVG_ES_Points__c == Trigger.OldMap.get(sport.Id).AVG_ES_Points__c) {
        scope.add(sport);
    }
}

if (!scope.isEmpty()) {
    UpdateCounterEsOnsp.UpdateSport(scope);
}
...
```

Doing this, `UpdateCounterEsOnsp.UpdateSport` won't be called by the trigger if a record is updated by the batch, so it won't run the same query twice.
By the way, this would also avoid trigger recursion.

If this is not enough, keep in mind that you can specify the scope size, so if it cannot handle 200 (the default value) record, you could try with 100 or lower, i.e. `Database.executeBatch(new UpdateCounterEsOnsp(), 100);`.